# Type 'ssize_t' could not be resolved eclipse cdt

Tags: c, eclipse, linux-kernel, eclipse-cdt, kernel-module

I'm learning to write a simple driver for linux (I have installed Lubuntu).
But I have problem. My IDE Eclipse cdt can't see some types.
`Type 'ssize_t' could not be resolved` But I'm included  and add include path in project, and I have enabled indexer.
Why Eclipse cdt cant see some types?

Comment: Do you have `#include <sys/types.h>` in the source files that use `ssize_t`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but still don't work(((

Answer (score 0):

Try Project->Clean and then Project->Build. Main reason for me why eclipse keeps nagging at me.